# Display last week date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I was trying to make a javascript calender function as like in Google Analytics. to display last week calander.

But couldn't figure it out for example.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() - (d.getDay() ? d.getDay() : 7) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
d.setTime(d.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);               
alert(d);
```

Result Sun Aug 24 2014 02:46:57 GMT+0545

but i want result in this format 08/24/2014

Comment: The one with the RegEx option `(new Date()).toISOString().replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*/,"$2\/$3\/$1")`

Comment: Not trying to be a bad person but how was this question upvoted? A google search on "Javascript date" returns more hits than one could thoroughly read through during a workday. Wasn't a Google Search plus rolling up sleeves by the OP the solution here?

Comment: You can use
`alert(new Date().toLocaleDateString());` 
This will give you the format you want and none US user the date in a format they understand.
If you want it exactly in the format you say you can use toLocaleDateString with some options
`alert(new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", {year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}));

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the formatting methods of Date, like this:

```
alert(d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' d.getFullYear())
```

**Edit**: Months are 0-based I believe, so should be like this instead (left previous version for reference):

```
alert((d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' d.getFullYear())
```